# How to store length of time in DB

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

What's the best way to store things like "7 years 4 months" (for example, years of experience) in the database.  Float?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718332/what-is-the-best-way-to-represent-a-timespan-in-sql-server-ce

Comment: Thanks for all the answers.  I think I'll use int.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Store a BIGINT number of seconds or ticks.

In your specific example (years of experience), it would be better to store the start date and calculate the amount of time when you read the database.

Answer (score 2):

Use **long** [read **bigint** for SQLServer]  to represent time diff converted to seconds

Comment: @JNK you are right. I have made necessary change, there is no mention of SQL Server inside the question.. except tag

Answer (score 2):

Since SQL-server 2005 lacks the time-only data-types, I would use an integer type, of appropriate size to hold the count of "some time interval" - seconds, milliseconds, etc. I would do all the translations (except comparisons) in the app tier; no reason for the DB to worry about them except as an int/bigint/etc

Answer (score 0):

Store it as is. I.e. a string `7 years 4 months`.
Why? Well lets think from the other end - what is 7 year (or 4 months)? On the surface one would think that it is a time interval, but it is not. Neither month nor year have static number of time units (days) in them, so the actual value would be different depending on the starting point for your interval.

Thanks for all the minuses, but this is in fact the only answer that addresses the question as is. The `7 years 4 months` is not a value that is serializable without starting point. Therefore presentation == value.

Comment: This is a pretty terrible idea.  What happens when he wants to know how much longer event a took than event b?  He needs to parse the strings?

Comment: then he is asking a wrong question. Correct question would be "what should I be storing" instead of "how"

Comment: I see what you're saying, so I gave you a +.   I think the question was a bit ambiguous, and I don't think the answer you've given is a good approach for what I *think* Prabhu is intending to ask, but based on the example cited, this is actually probably the best advice.   If (a big if, based on my ignorance of the big picture) you're wanting to statically store someone's answer to "Years Of Employment" (rather than, say, calculate it based on start date, etc.), then allowing the user to enter a string like "7 years 4 months," and storing it as-is makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

As this field is a variable, the best way to approach this is to store the (estimated) date of the event.

The time until now should be calculated at run-time.

Edit: If needed, you can also store the end date to use in the run-time calculation.

Comment: that won't work for events that ended before.  If I had something that ran for 2 hours 3 weeks ago, your method wouldn't work

Comment: You're making unjustified assumptions.  What if he's storing the duration of an event?

Answer (score 0):

It depends, if you store the time period - i.e. The Start date and end date, this becomes a derivable value, and you can calculate everytime.

If you are going to be storing 7.4 to simulate a year.month then you are limited in your granularity. You could never display weeks, what would happen if a value for 7.14 was added?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really need precision to the second if you're storing something like years of experience.  I would just store the number in years and store it as a float.

So "7 years 4 months" would be equal = 7 + 4/12 = 7.333..