# How do I format a timespan to show me total hours?

Tags: c#, timespan

I want to save the user's hours worked in a database `varchar` column, but by default, the formatted value includes days if the number of hours is more than 24.  I just want the total number of hours.

For example: if a user works 10:00:00 hours today, then 13:00:00 hours tomorrow, and 3:30:00 hours the day after tomorrow then the formatted total I want is 26:30:00.  Instead, I am seeing 1.2:30:00.

How can I get the formatting I want?

Also, when I save the value 40:00:00 in the database manually, and try to read it into a `TimeSpan` later, I get a bug.

How can I save the hours in the database the way I want, and still be able to read it back into a `TimeSpan` later?

Comment: Are you asking about data in the database or the `TimeSpan` structure in the BCL? Your question is confusing.

Comment: As suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/744929/897326), it's best to store ticks in the database, rather than a formatted TimeSpan. Then you don't have this problem.

Comment: Vote on the feature suggestion, then wait a decade for MS to get around to it: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/4050034-add-standard-formats-to-timespan-which-allow-the-f

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try [TimeSpan.TotalHours](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours.aspx)

```
String timeStamp = "40:00:00";
var segments = timeStamp.Split(':');

TimeSpan t = new TimeSpan(0, Convert.ToInt32(segments[0]), 
               Convert.ToInt32(segments[1]), Convert.ToInt32(segments[2]));
string time = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", 
           ((int) t.TotalHours), t.Minutes, t.Seconds);
```

Comment: @Bala it get something so...(40.166666663) (it is a example) and how do i convert this 40:00:00 to timespan? i tried  timespan x=timespan.Parse("40:00:00"); it get a bug

Comment: @angel `TimeSpan.FromHours(40.0);`

Comment: @angel for the 40.166666 issue, you can use TimeSpan.TotalHours as integet and then TimeSpan.Minutes and TimeSpan.Seconds to format the string the way you want it.

Comment: @angel, see my edit, you can use `FromHours()` to convert 40 hours

Comment: @Bala how do i convert  "40:00:00" to double then?  because it is saved in database ...

Comment: @angel you can use split on your input string and extract different segments as shown above.

Comment: i plus it one hour more and i get 41.00:00:00 what is this  value? after first point?

Comment: I don't understand. Can you rephrase your question? are you trying to add one hour to a timespan ?

Comment: i want to be able than to have a time and plus with another time (one or two or more ) hours

Comment: You can try `timeSpan.Add(anotherTimeSpan);`

Comment: and finally what is it going to return? i want it returns hours, minutes, seconds... is it going to return it?

Comment: `Add()` returns a new TimeSpan instance. you can do `newTimeSpan.TotalHours` to get hours, `newTimeSpan.Minutes` and `newTimeSpan.Seconds` to get minutes and seconds.

Comment: almost! the problem now is totalHours get if it is 40:20:00 i got  40,3333 and with minutes and seconds i got finnaly 40,333333333:20:00

Comment: (int) before than time.TotalHours+":+time.Minutes.ToString()+":"+time.Seconds all this as string and i printed it, do you believe i dont get bugs with this?

Comment: it should work but rather than concatenating string like that, use `string.Format()` which is more readable and efficient but your statement should work too.

Comment: Noyce! (So much easier than built in crap)

Answer (score 30):

You could do something like:

```
TimeSpan time = ...;
string timeForDisplay = (int)time.TotalHours + time.ToString(@"\:mm\:ss");
```

Comment: seriously? ... `TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromHours(40) + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)`

Comment: Or even easier: `TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan(40, 30, 0)` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk8a3558.aspx