# Timeformat that show total elapsed minutes

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, datetime, string-formatting

I wanted to give the user the option to choose the format in which a timer is displayed. The timeformats a user kan choose:

```
mm\:ss
mm\:ss\.f
mm\:ss\.ff
hh\:mm\:ss
hh\:mm\:ss\.f
hh\:mm\:ss\.ff
```

Then in code i have a timespan that is converted to String like:

```
Return timespan.ToString(TimeFormat)
```

The thing is that if a user uses the format mm:ss then the Minutes are showed and when it elapse 59 minutes it starts at zero again. What i would like is to display the total minutes. So 60minutes43seconds

I've read the whole MS documentation but can't find a solution for this.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible using the standard `.ToString()` formatters. Might I recommend checking out something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074363/how-do-i-format-a-timespan-to-show-me-total-hours

Comment: What if it is 120 minutes?  Your formats show two characters for minutes?

Comment: You should create you own function (may be overwrite ToString if you don't use it anywhere else).In that function you can check input and for those who starts with mm declare your own processing.

Comment: Doesn't creating your own ToString take a lot of CPU time? You have to check each time if there is an hour or not, if so change the Format type. FYI: The format is hooked up to a timer which is refreshed by a DispatcherTimer at 60hz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the advice i got from the comments and some more googling i dind't find a very framework like solution so i inded up with a dirty `Select Case` that works like a charm.

```
Select Case objSettings.TimeFormat
    Case "m\:ss"
        Return String.Format("{0}:{1:00}", Math.Floor(time.TotalMinutes), time.Seconds)
    Case "m\:ss\.f"
        Return String.Format("{0}:{1}", Math.Floor(time.TotalMinutes), time.ToString("ss\.f"))
    Case "m\:ss\.ff"
        Return String.Format("{0}:{1}", Math.Floor(time.TotalMinutes), time.ToString("ss\.ff"))
    Case "mm\:ss"
        Return String.Format("{0:0#}:{1:00}", Math.Floor(time.TotalMinutes), time.Seconds)
    Case "mm\:ss\.f"
        Return String.Format("{0:0#}:{1:00}", Math.Floor(time.TotalMinutes), time.ToString("ss\.f"))
    Case "mm\:ss\.ff"
        Return String.Format("{0:0#}:{1:00}", Math.Floor(time.TotalMinutes), time.ToString("ss\.ff"))
    Case "hh\:mm\:ss"
        Return String.Format("{0:0#}:{1}", Math.Floor(time.TotalHours), time.ToString("mm\:ss"))
    Case "hh\:mm\:ss\.f"
        Return String.Format("{0:0#}:{1}", Math.Floor(time.TotalHours), time.ToString("mm\:ss\.f"))
    Case "hh\:mm\:ss\.ff"
        Return String.Format("{0:0#}:{1}", Math.Floor(time.TotalHours), time.ToString("mm\:ss\.ff"))
    Case Else
        Return time.ToString(objSettings.TimeFormat)
End Select
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just return a custom formatted string. Something like this:

```
if (TimeFormat == "some format")
    return $"{timespan.TotalMinutes} minutes, {timespan.Seconds} seconds";
```

Comment: I think this should be `{timespan.TotalMinutes}` - otherwise it will just wrap around again.

Comment: @Neil: Right, I modified my answer. Thanks.

Comment: I think the OP wants to show `timespan.Seconds` rather than `timespan.TotalSeconds`. For example "60 minutes, 43 seconds" and not "60 minutes, 3643 seconds".

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need the 'g' format:

> This specifier outputs only what is needed. It is culture-sensitive and takes the form [-][d’:’]h’:’mm’:’ss[.FFFFFFF].

[Details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-timespan-format-strings)

Comment: Thanks for the Tip, however this doesn't give me any controls on how many milliseconds the user wants to see.

Comment: If the user is bothered about >60 minutes, are they really bothered about milliseconds?