# How do I convert TimeSpan days into hours format

Tags: c#, .net

I have a function that given minutes converts it to a string in the following format `hh:mm`.

The function works fine, except when the minutes excedes 24 hours. For example, if the input is `1920 minutes` the epected output is `32:00` but, is `08:00` (1 day + **8 hours**).

The function:

```
private string NumberToDurationFormat(int number)
{
    TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(number);
    return timeSpan.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
}
```

Comment: Maybe `$"{ts.TotalHours:N0}:{ts.Minutes}"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I format a timespan to show me total hours?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074363/how-do-i-format-a-timespan-to-show-me-total-hours)

Comment: @TheGeneral That wouldn't pad the `TotalHours` to 2 digits.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay and there are some more issues with it. See https://dotnetfiddle.net/ATPVdY , where I compare it to a slightly modified version: `{(int)ts.TotalHours:00}:{ts.Minutes:00}`

Comment: Does @Coner Stoop answer have any implications? In performance for example, compared to yours?

Comment: Outside readability, I'd be surprised to actually see performance differences if this isn't executed a huge amount of times per second. But if you want to be sure, setup a quick Benchmarkdotnet and run the horses.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay and Fildor good points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this.
by doing toString with the `00` it makes sure you have 2 characters.

```
private string NumberToDurationFormat(int number)
{
    TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(number);
    return ((int)timeSpan.TotalHours).ToString("00") + ":" + timeSpan.Minutes.ToString("00");
}
```