# TimeSpan and ToString()

Tags: c#, .net, timespan

I want to display minutes, seconds, and milliseconds saved in `TimeSpan`. It should look like this:

```cs
var d1 = new DateTime(2020, 12, 1, 12, 00, 00);
var d2 = new DateTime(2020, 12, 1, 10, 12, 30);
        
var d = d1 - d2;
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString(@"mm\:ss\:fff"));
```

But it returns `47:30:000` which is only partially true, because it ignored one hour. I want it to be converted into minutes, not ignored.

Comment: So even if the difference would be weeks you still would only list it as minutes?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074363/how-do-i-format-a-timespan-to-show-me-total-hours - it’s about hours but the sam is true for minutes

Comment: @RandRandom no, because in my case the TimeSpan would be no longer than a few hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.6) has a property for getting the total number of minutes contained in it, as a `double` value: [TimeSpan.TotalMinutes Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalminutes?view=netframework-4.6).

Note that if your `TimeSpan`'s duration is not in whole minutes you will get a fraction part:

```
var d1 = new DateTime(2020, 12, 1, 12, 00, 00);
var d2 = new DateTime(2020, 12, 1, 10, 12, 30);
var d = d1 - d2;
Console.WriteLine(d.TotalMinutes);
```

Output:

```
107.5
```

Note that `TimeSpan` has similar properties for [`TotalDays`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totaldays?view=netframework-4.6), [`TotalHours`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalhours?view=netframework-4.6), [`TotalSeconds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalseconds?view=netframework-4.6), [`TotalMilliseconds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds?view=netframework-4.6).

---

**Update:**
Based on the comments below, here's a solution that prints in a format splitting minutes, seconds and milliseconds:

```
var d1 = new DateTime(2020, 12, 1, 12, 00, 00);
var d2 = new DateTime(2020, 12, 1, 10, 12, 30);
var d = d1 - d2;
double totalMin = d.TotalMinutes;
int totalMinInt = (int)totalMin;             // will get only the whole minutes.
Console.WriteLine(totalMinInt.ToString() +   // print the whole minutes part
                  ":" +
                  d.ToString(@"ss\:fff"));   // print the fraction part
```

Output:

```
107:30:000
```

Comment: So it's not possible to do what I want with ToString? Because then I will have to create multiple properties to handle minutes, seconds, and milliseconds, which is entirely doable, but it's extra layer of work. Edit Ok it actually won't help, because `TotalMinutes` contains even milliseconds, so it won't help.

Comment: @Walter125 `Console.WriteLine((int)d.TotalMinutes + ":" + d.Seconds.ToString("00") + ":" + d.Milliseconds.ToString("000"));` should give you the value in the required format

Comment: Updated my answer with a possible way to print it as the OP requires.

Comment: @wohlstad I have already done it by taking `Minutes` and adding to it converted `Hours` and `Days` (in my case it shouldn't take more than a few hours, but can do it just in case), but I'm marking your post as solution because it seems to give desired results.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need TimeSpan.TotalMinutes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalminutes?view=net-7.0

In your case it could be:

```
Console.WriteLine($@"{(int)d.TotalMinutes}:{d:ss\:fff}");
```

Comment: Then I'm going to lose seconds and milliseconds.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the example.

Comment: well done https://dotnetfiddle.net/s51qjX

Comment: I think it should be `Console.WriteLine($"{(int)d.TotalMinutes:d0}:{d:ss\:fff}");`, because we want the minutes to print only once. And we must take the int part of the minutes, otherwise they might round up. In this case we get 108 instead 107 without `(int)`.