# Insert Elapsed Time in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql

I want to insert elapsed times using the C# Stopwatch into a SQL Server so we can average the times using a SQL Script.

```
var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();
stopwatch.Stop();
var elapsedTime = stopwatch.Elapsed;
```

I'm inserting the time like this...

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ElapsedTime", SqlDbType.Time);
```

The data type in the database is ...

```
ElapsedTime(time(7),null)
```

Getting this error...

```
SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.
```

I just want to insert the elapsed time in the database like this...

```
00:01:44.9383728
```

Here is how I am putting into database...

```
internal bool TimesToSql(TimeSpan elapsedTime)
    {
        try
        {
            const string statement = "INSERT INTO Database.dbo.TestProgress(MachineName, ElapsedTime) " +
                                     "VALUES(@MachineName, @ElapsedTime)";
            var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringLocalDb());
            var cmd = new SqlCommand(statement, conn);
            var machineName = Environment.MachineName;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@MachineName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ElapsedTime", SqlDbType.Time);
            //
            cmd.Parameters["@MachineName"].Value = Environment.MachineName;
            cmd.Parameters["@ElapsedTime"].Value = elapsedTime;
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

            return true;

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _logger.Log(Loglevel.Error, "Boom: {0}", exception.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The ultimate goal is to get the average time from let's say x amount of elapsed times, if I can do that using string, then I will format them to strings

Comment: Why have you made the type a `time(7)`? That's a time of day, not an elapsed time. (Although your error message is a bit confusing.) Where are you specifying the *value* for the parameter? It would help if we could see more code...

Comment: @Jon It should just be an int shouldn't it?

Comment: Well it looks like SQL Server doesn't really *have* a type that maps to TimeSpan. You might want to store a number of ticks instead. But the fact that it's complaining about a SqlDateTime overflow suggests to me that it might not even be this parameter. Can you come up with a short but complete program that demonstrates the problem? What does your SQL look like?

Comment: @JonSkeet I added the SQL code to insert the times into the table

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to represent a timespan in SQL Server CE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718332/what-is-the-best-way-to-represent-a-timespan-in-sql-server-ce) (completely relevant to non-ce).

Comment: @ErikPhilips If I'm forced into using Ticks then ok, but if I could store the times as `00:01:02.8373788` then I would prefer that, I've never tried to get times using Ticks

Comment: There are no [SQL Server Datatypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx) that represent a TimeSpan.  The closest you can get is a hacky, how much time after a given point in time which in SQL Server will look like a date, not a TimeSpan.

Comment: @JonSkeet .. Sorry if I speak out of turn. I was wondering why JonK cannot use Time(7) to hold the elapsed time? What ever time is saved would be the elapsed time.

Comment: @t_m: What would happen if it were ever 25 hours? Even if you always know that it's less than 24 hours, it's still a hack IMO (as is the fact that `DateTime.TimeOfDay` returns a `TimeSpan`. Both .NET and SQL Server have a long way to go in terms of representing the various date/time types which we might want, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet .. Am assuming it's less than 24 hours. I don't think it's a hack. If you use a string it will use more storage. Using Time data type the OP will be able to query easier where Time taken is greater than nn.nn.nnnnn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly do you want to do with the timespan in the database? If all you want to do is sort and aggregate, you could go for a `bigint` in the database.

Internally in .NET a TimeSpan is nothing but a `long` value that stores the number of 'Ticks' (see the [.NET source code for TimeSpan](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/timespan.cs)) and a bunch of conversions of course to seconds, milliseconds etc.

When you load the value again from the database you can recreate the TimeSpan from the ticks stored in the database. You will not lose precision.

You can even perform aggregate functions (Min, Max, Avg, Sum) on the database values and you will still get valid TimeSpans when you later load the value in C#.

If however you have a requirement to query the database for values of, for example, more than 5 mins, you'd need to do the math of figuring out how to express 5 mins as ticks.
In the source code linked earlier, you'll see that there are 10,000,000 ticks in a second. So it's hardly rocket science ;)

Comment: Looks like I'm not the only one who figured this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/744929/64096

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain your elapsedTime is going to be less than 24 hours, you could change

cmd.Parameters["@ElapsedTime"].Value = elapsedTime;

to

cmd.Parameters["@ElapsedTime"].Value = elapsedTime.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss\.ffff");

I'm not sure there's another way to convert a timespan to sql time. Note that if your duration is over 24 hours, the overflow will be truncated.

Answer (score 1):

Did a quick test in SSMS. I think it's your calculation that is incorrect. Cannot have 84 seconds as maximun is 59.

This did not work because seconds cannot be more than 84.

```
declare @tim time(7)
set @tim = '00:01:84.9383728'
select @tim
```

This worked ..

```
declare @tim time(7)
set @tim = '00:01:59.9383728'
select @tim
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just store the time using a `float` data type in the database? If you're usually measuring in the order of seconds and minutes then just store the total number of seconds. If you usually measure milliseconds then store the total milliseconds. "Keep It Simple, but don't get stupid."

Unless your application needs to store the time as "X month X days X hours X minutes X.XX seconds" ... which I bet is unlikely the case.